# HotChocolate GraphQL (.NET Core) How to drill down nested Classes

Tags: entity-framework-core, nested, drilldown, hotchocolate

I am new to GraphQL. I am testing HotChocolate following a simple article and seems that was easy to drill down to nested classes using [UseSelection] annotation in the Resolvers, however, I am using V11 and I realize did no work anymore, I would love to know how to simply drill down to nested classes using V11 like this:

query {
customers {
name
departments { name }
}

Thank you

Comment: This is the Article: https://chillicream.com/blog/2020/03/18/entity-framework

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution on HotChocolate Slack Channel. It is basically still the same but classes are in a different package and had been renamed.  The way to go is using Projections:
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/projections/

Also, it is interesting to read this article, if you are planing or using EntityFramework:
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/integrations/entity-framework/

Thank You anyways